# Find elements where name is different than id using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I write jQuery expression that will find inputs where the `name` attribute value is different from the `id` attribute value?

This should be found

```
<input name="foo" id="bar" />
```

This should not be found

```
<input name="foo" id="foo" />
```

Trivial stuff like `$('input[name!=id]')` fails, because the `[]` expression [expects a constant on the right hand side](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/).

Comment: I'm not sure that it is possible to perform such comparisons inside the selector - is there any reason why you are not able to iterate over each item and verify them individually?

Comment: I'd prefer a selector, but I'll settle with the answer by @Rejith

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this using **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** function. And use trim to make sure.

**Edit Simple version**

```
$('input').filter(function(){
    return this.id != this.name;
});
```

If there are any issues because of trailing or leading spaces, then the following can be used.

```
$('input').filter(function(){
    thisID = $.trim(this.id);
    thisName =  $.trim(this.name);
    return thisID != thisName;
});
```

Comment: @canon without trim if there is a accidental space such as id = "foo " it won't think it is equal to name = "foo". So if OP wants to count "foo " and "foo" as different then you're correct its arbitrary but I think he'd want those to be the same.

Comment: `document.getElementById("test")` isn't going to find an element with an `id` of `"test "`. Spaces matter. That being the case, it doesn't make much sense to use a fuzzy match unless explicitly desired.